# Facebook like button counter reset to 0

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, counter, facebook-likebox

My like button counter displays 1 likes for a month.

I've checked the number through http://graph.facebook.com/http://www.arthurimmo.com/ and get the "real number"

I did the debug process http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.arthurimmo.com%2F

But still displays 1 like on my website

Any idea how i can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The number of one like is for the url: http://www.arthurimmo.com.x30.poliris.net/index.htm
Try swapping the og:url to http://www.arthurimmo.com 
Sometimes it becomes messy with redirects and rewrites for like counting.